# Access GraphQL playground locally with Vercel function

Tags: reactjs, vercel, apollo-server

I have an Apollo Server set up in a Vercel function, which works flawlessly when deployed on a remote server. However, I'm having trouble accessing the Apollo Sandbox locally using the `vercel dev` command, as I keep getting a *No routes matched location /api/xxx* warning. I suspect this is a redirection issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. My front-end is built with React, and I'm using React Router for routing.

Can anyone help me figure out why this error is occurring and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your code.